# GET() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, web.py

I understood this seems like a common question, but the codes is rather simple so I can't really figure it out..

```
from VideoCapture import Device 
import web
import Image

web.config.debug=False   

class Image:
    def GET(self):
        cam = Device()  
        return cam.getImage()

app=web.application(('/(.*)','Image'),globals())
app.run()
```

Here I just want to grab the image from the camera and send it to my web application.
when I entered the url：`http://127.0.0.1:8080/`
 there is only one messege:internal server error
and this is what comes second in the interpreter:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 396, in handle_class
return tocall(*args)
TypeError: GET() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
127.0.0.1:8188 - - [20/Jan/2014 19:38:33] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 500 Internal Server Error
```

The GET function gets only argument self so I am really confused. Thanks.
By the way, the line "web.config.debug=False" should have nothing to do with my codes.
Thanks for anyone who looked into it.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback

Answer (score 11):

You've captured the URL in your route, and that is being sent to the handler. You need to accept that argument there:

```
def GET(self, url):
    ...
```

Or, alternatively, don't capture it in the URL:

```
('/','Image')
```